# Suppress output from both CMake and make

Tags: makefile, cmake

I have two bash scripts, `./build.sh` and `./patch.sh`.
`./patch.sh` runs 16 patches on a source directory to update it to the latest version.
`./build.sh` builds this directory with `cmake` and `make`, all the while running a spinner to show progress.
The problem is, even when I redirect `cmake` and `make` to /dev/null, the output of both commands still shows, so, instead of looking like this:

```
[insert spinning spinner here]
```

it looks like this:

```
|Building librandom.so [100%]
/Complete!
|Installing librandom.so [100%]
\Complete!
[insert still spinning spinner here]
```

I would like to silence the output of make **and** cmake in my bash script, so that the spinner can run without other command-line output.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You should instead remove the spinner and allow all of the build output to pass through to the terminal.  The default mode of any build script **must** be as verbose as possible, otherwise the poor schmuck who will have to debug your build script on an automated build robot to which they don't have direct access, using only a log of its output, will be in a world of hurt.

Comment: (I did not make that scenario up.  I have *been* that schmuck.  Repeatedly.)

Comment: You're redirecting with `&>`? (Yes, I wish CMake did `make VERBOSE=1` by default, so I wouldn't have to ask to rerun it in verbose mode every time to find out what's going on.)